# Should I assign String message to some variable on corner cases and return in at the end of method, or immediately?

Tags: java, methods, return, naming-conventions

As in the topic name, I wonder what is the best convention

Comment: This is very opinion based. Some say the first one is better ("return as early as possible" and "fail fast") and others say it is better to return at only one point (to make debugging easier).

Comment: This boils down to preference mostly. It's easier to debug and read if you minimize the number of returns, but it might make some methods easier to implement if you return at several points, rather than at a single spot.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is essentially another question: what makes your code easier to read and maintain?

[Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/), a well-known author and programming guru, suggests a refactoring called [Replace Nested Conditional with Guard Clauses](http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html).

I am definitely more of the mind to use [guard clauses](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuardClause) because they usually make the code cleaner and easier to read. However, once in a while there is a scenario where the [intent](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/196139/programming-by-intention-depth-first-or-breadth-first) of the code comes through clearer without them.